# Plot of ratio of two integrals:

Tags: numerics, integration, complex-analysis

Consider the following integrals
$$
I_1(x) =\int_0^\infty\mathrm dy \frac{F(x + \mathrm iy) − F(x −\mathrm iy)}{\mathrm e^{2πy}-1},
$$

And

$$I_2(x) =\int_1^x F(t)dt$$

Where, $ F(z) = \sin^2[π\Gamma(z)/(2z)]$

> > I want to plot (with considerable accuracy)
> > $$R(x)=I_1(x)/I_2(x)$$

> > Also , see if it's apparent from plot : $R(x)\rightarrow0$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$

I want growth rate of local minimas and Maximas of $I_1(x)$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$

See [this MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3570663/702232) for more details .

Comment: This is in essence a duplicate of a previous question asked on this forum. The problems discussed there are all the same here.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth I asked for second Integral in previous question , first Integral is new here and equally tricky .

Comment: @Bambi as far as I can tell it's "tricky"' in the same way the other integrals were.